# How to click form button in cypress without triggering page load

Tags: javascript, forms, click, cypress, pageload

When clicking a form button in a cypress test, I fail to be able to do any additional testing on the page until the page response has finished. This is a problem, as I'm trying to test for the visibility of a loading spinner, after clicking the form button.

Test example that doesn't work:

```
 cy.get('#username').type('testusername')
    .get('#password').type('password')
    .get('#login-button').click().then(() => {
       cy.get('#login-spinner').should('be.visible');
    });
```

The problem is that the last part, `cy.get('#login-spinner').should('be.visible');` is not executed until the page has loaded. I have tried moving it outside the `.then()` clause as well, but the result is the same - cypress seems very adamant on having to wait for the form response to load:

[image: Page load after click]

`cy.get('#login-spinner').should('be.visible');` is then executed on the page that loads after the form click, at which point the spinner is hidden again, causing the test to fail.